# Teamcity build canceling infinitely only visually

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

When I cancel a running build, the build stops and cancels but visually the build is still cancelling and this never stop.

**¿Why I know that the build is cancelled?**

Because I can run another build without problems. My pipeline only have one step, Unity compile step from Unity plugin to Teamcity but I tried the same with a .net build in another project and happened the same.

[Builds](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0swBh.png)

This is the log throwed by the build when is cancelled.

[Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opH9K.png)

Restart the server not fix it.